# Two Regedit windows display different keys in the same place

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

**I'm tearing my hair out here.**

I have two Registry Editor windows open on the same key but they are displaying different contents and I don't understand why.

[image: Absolute heresy!]

Both windows were opened through another application that helps me find registry keys. If I close them both and attempt to open it manually, it opens the one with the structure on the right.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Why is this happening? Which one should I insert keys into? Why does the other one even exist?

Comment: Just noticed that they are in fact 2 different executables. One is in `C:\Windows` and the other in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. I still don't understand why an entirely separate registry for 64-bit applications is needed.

Comment: There is a healthy amount of information about this within the Stack Exchange world:  [Why/how are Registry Entries Hidden in Regedit but visible in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31549791), with a reference that points to the following:  [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=VS.85).aspx)